# Change label color when checkbox checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

```
<label class="black">Blacks
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
```

I want to apply below CSS for my `<label>` when checkbox is checked:

```
border-bottom: 1px solid #7f7f7f;
```

Can anyone help me to resolve?

Comment: what have you tried so far? SO is not a write me code community mate.. read on `.change()`

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/3082296)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<label class="black">Blacks
   <input type="checkbox">
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>


$( 'label' ).on( 'click', 'input:checkbox', function () {
      $( this ).parent().toggleClass( 'highlight', this.checked ); 
    });
```

Apply below style for label in css

```
label.highlight{border-bottom: 1px solid #7f7f7f;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to modifying your HTML structure slightly, you could do this without any Javascript.

You need to place the label after the input, so it allows selecting the label using the adjacent selector (`+`), and then based on `:checked` pseudo selector, you can toggle the border on the label.

Check the snippet below to see how it works:

```css
#myCheckbox:checked + label {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #7f7f7f;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox">

<label class="black" for="myCheckbox">
  Blacks
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
```

Comment: Perfect, label comes *after* checkbox so adjacent selector works. That's what I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

Use `parent()` and `toggleClass` method from jquery to select the label and add/remove class

```js
function toggleCheck(elem) {
  console.log(elem)
  $(elem).parent().toggleClass('borderBottom')


}
```

```css
.borderBottom {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #7f7f7f;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="black">Blacks
  <input type="checkbox" onchange="toggleCheck(this)">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
label{
  position: relative;
}
.checkmark{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -4px;
  height: 1px;
  background: red;
}
input:checked + .checkmark{
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<label class="black">Blacks
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Find your checkbox inside your span and use add remove class.

```js
$('.black').find('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
  if (this.checked)
    $(this).parent().addClass('testClass');
  else
    $(this).parent().removeClass('testClass');
});
```

```css
.testClass {
border-bottom: 1px solid #7f7f7f;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="black">Blacks
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
```